# Live Template is not supported in *.scss but *.css and *.less in PHPStorm

Tags: sass, phpstorm, live-templates

I set a few frequently used live templates like:

### sm

```
@media (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
    $START$
}
```

### md

```
@media (max-width: @screen-md-max) {
    $START$
}
```

### lg

```
@media (max-width: @screen-lg-max) {
    $START$
}
```

They are all working well in .less file, however when I switch to SCSS, they are all not working.

I have checked live template context to CSS.

What can I do to make it works with SCSS file too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating live template, make sure correct context are checked, for live template I wrote above, I should check `ruleset list`. Of course, if you don't know which one to check, you can just check all checkbox in the program language context. There shouldn't have any big deal.